# how can i make a unique request for `counter_cache`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So, i have a two model `Campaign` and `CampaignSubscription`

`CampaignSubscription` model
 I have this relation

```
belongs_to :campaign, inverse_of: :campaign_subscriptions, counter_cache: true, required: true
```

I don't get no unique number of subscriptions.

```
belongs_to :campaign, inverse_of: :campaign_subscriptions, required: true

counter_culture :campaign, column_name: proc { |model|
self.where(lead_id: model.lead_id, campaign_id: model.campaign_id).count > 1 ? nil : 'campaign_subscriptions_count' }
```

But I think it's wrong and will cause N+1.

Now when the user creates the next CampaignSubscription object, I’m not receiving a unique number of subscriptions. I need to make the number of subscriptions unique to the user (Lead). How to more cleanly organize the code?

Comment: Don't you need to define the counter on the Campaign model instead? Why'd you want a counter on the associated model in a one-to-many?

Comment: Or you are trying to achieve something out of the scope of what a counter cache is meant for... could you please define the usecase of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need uniq count leads from `campaign subscription` for example `uniq_count = campaign.campaign_subscriptions.pluck(:lead_id).uniq.count`

Comment: You can check  the https://github.com/r7kamura/conditional_counter_cache gem, you could add a condition that return false if the record's value is not unique and it won't increment the counter.

Comment: Why don't count this in a model method. It seems to concern another relationship, through another model, so using counter cache will never work. I could make a suggestion, but I need more info on when the Lead model is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define this as a method on the campaign subscription class, instead of trying some kind of counter cache. I would only use a counter cache on the parent model to describe counts in a simple one-to-many (maybe with a filter publishedL:true), but not for counting related records in the same table. Use a model method for that:

```
def some_describing_method_name
  campaign.campaign_subscriptions.pluck(:lead_id).uniq.count
end
```